# AsyncSocket doesn't call delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asyncsocket

I have a weird issue trying to use AsyncSocket. In my app I actually need synchronous sockets because I handle all communication in background myself on a different level. So I try to write wrapper around AsyncSocket class SyncSocket. Here is code:

```
// SyncSocket.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AsyncSocket.h"

@interface SyncSocket : NSObject <AsyncSocketDelegate> {
    AsyncSocket* _asyncSocket;
    NSTimeInterval _connectTimeout;
    NSTimeInterval _readTimeout;
    NSTimeInterval _writeTimeout;
    BOOL _waiting;
    BOOL _nsLog;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL waiting;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL nsLog;

- (id) initWithConnectTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) connectTimeout readTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) readTimeout writeTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) writeTimeout;

- (BOOL) connectToHost: (NSString*) host onPort: (UInt16) port;

@end

// SyncSocket.m
#import "SyncSocket.h"

@implementation SyncSocket
@synthesize waiting = _waiting;
@synthesize nsLog = _nsLog;

//
// Constructor/destructor
//

- (id) initWithConnectTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) connectTimeout readTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) readTimeout writeTimeout: (NSTimeInterval) writeTimeout {
    [super init];
    if (self == nil)
        return self;

    _connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
    _readTimeout = readTimeout;
    _writeTimeout = writeTimeout;
    _waiting = NO;

    _asyncSocket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate: self];

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [_asyncSocket release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL) connectToHost: (NSString*) host onPort: (UInt16) port {
    if (self.nsLog)
        NSLog (@"connectToHost: %@ onPort: %d", host, port);

    _waiting = YES;
    NSError* err = nil;
    if (![_asyncSocket connectToHost: host
                      onPort: port
                     withTimeout: _connectTimeout
                   error: &err])
        return NO;

    while (self.waiting && [_asyncSocket isConnected] == NO) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01];
    }


    return [_asyncSocket isConnected];
}

- (void) writeData: (NSData*) data {
    _waiting = YES;
    [_asyncSocket writeData: data withTimeout: _writeTimeout tag: 0];

    while (self.waiting) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01];
    }
}


//
// AsyncSocket delegates
// 
- (BOOL)onSocketWillConnect:(AsyncSocket *)sock {
    if (self.nsLog)
        NSLog (@"onSocketWillConnect:");
    return YES;
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag {
    if (self.nsLog)
        NSLog (@"didWriteDataWithTag: %d", tag);
    _waiting = NO;
}

- (void) onSocket: (AsyncSocket*) sock willDisconnectWithError: (NSError*) err {
    if (self.nsLog)
        NSLog (@"willDisconnectWithError: %d", [err code]);

    _waiting = NO;
}

- (void) onSocket: (AsyncSocket*) sock didConnectToHost: (NSString*) host port: (UInt16) port {
    if (self.nsLog)
        NSLog (@"didConnectToHost: %@ port: %d", host, port);

    _waiting = NO;
}

@end
```

The problem is: AsyncSocket connects to the host just fine, but my delegate didConnetToHost is never called. And if I debug AsyncSocket code I can see that even though delegate is set `respondsToSelector` fails. Looks like there is some strange memory violation or something but I have no idea where did I do mistake.

Any ideas? Is there a good example on how to wrap AsyncSocket to be synchronous socket?

PS: Just to be clear: XCode 3.2.5, iPhone Simulator 4.2.

Update: The reason I'm trying to wrap it with SyncSocket is because I wanted to hide all socket delegate stuff from business logic of application. I need to use socket connection in many different places and I don't want to implement low level socket functions (like detecting state of the socket, receiving header of the message then body etc) in many different places. I want to have simple interface where I can open/send/receive and don't worry about low level implementation. I do understand that network connectivity should be run in separate thread and that's fine - making one background worker in the main thread is not a problem.

So I took InterfaceTest sample from AsyncSocket repository as a starting point. Removed DNS related stuff from there. Works fine. didConnect get called, everything is shiny.

I added then to the project my SyncSocket implementation to see what's wrong with it. Project can be downloaded here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6402890/NetworkTest.zip - may be somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong - I got a feeling that I'm not using threads properly in SyncSocket.

If I use in waiting loop both `asyncSocket is Connected` and my internal `self.waiting` - it gets out of that loop and `didConnect` is called (but AFTER the loop is finished). If I try to use only my `self.waiting` which is set in didConnect - `didConnect` never called and application hangs.

Anybody can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: That did not make any difference. Strange thing - after calling connect method - onSocketWillConnect is called and then nothing. I'm getting out of the loop because isConnected becomes TRUE.

Comment: change your init method: if (self = [super init]) { /* initialization */ } return self;

Comment: Tried. Does't change anything. It's an equivalent to what I had as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a problem. Looks like I had to change waiting loop from using:

```
[[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01]
```

To using RunLoop:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.01]];
```

Comment: I just wanted to thank you, as I've been stuck with the same problem for 2 days now. Nowhere in the GCDAsyncSockets is this mentioned, and for us beginners, it is very confusing. My code would execute fine, but delegates would get called only after the socket had disconnected & the delegate queue set to null. Again, thank you, you saved my day !

Comment: No problem :) Glad it helped somebody else